# function st_geomfromtext(unknown) does not exist PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, postgis

I have this query:

```
  SELECT
      name, location, date, price_type, price, currency, category, amount, id
    FROM
      jobs 
    WHERE 
      status = 'ACTIVE' 
      AND CAST(category AS TEXT ) IN ${categories}
      AND ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0))'), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5 5)'));
      `);
```

Everything worked fine untill I tried to use ST_GeomFromText when I got the following errro: `function st_geomfromtext(unknown) does not exist`. I've looked into the documentation and It appears to be correct format but for some reason it doesn't work and I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Do you have the PostGIS extension/bundle installed on your database server?

Comment: "Everything worked fine..."  We have no idea what "everything" might consist of.  Did you use other postgis features?  If so, which ones?  Please provide concrete examples.

Comment: ST_GeomFromText() takes text as input, what happens when you CAST your input explicitly to TEXT? `ST_GeomFromText(CAST('POINT(5 5)' AS TEXT)`

Answer (score 2):

As always with this kind of problem, there are three possibilities:

- You are connected to a database where PostGIS hasn't been installed with

  ```
  CREATE EXTENSION postgis SCHEMA public;
  ```
- Your `search_path` does not contain the schema where the extension is installed, in the above case `public`. You can fix that by naming the schema explicitly:

  ```
  SELECT public.st_geomfromtext(...);
  ```
- The arguments you supply to the function are of a data type that cannot be implicitly converted to the function parameter data types. Since you are supplying only one argument of type `unknown`, that cannot be your problem, because `unknown` can be converted to anything.